# Regex - limit user input to 0-128

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a regex that limits user input to 3 digits in the range of
0-128?

I've been trying `\d{1,3}` but this allows for a match more than the 0-128 range.

Thanks

Comment: Why should this be a RegEx?

Comment: cuz it's easy to check than me doing if else loops later on.

Comment: `if (parseInt(value, 10) >= 0 && parseInt(value, 10) <= 128)`?

Comment: agreed.. but what I am doing will go with a regex, that I already have in place. The question here is just a piece of that puzzle. :) appreciate the answer though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/\b([0-9]{1,2}|1[01][0-9]|12[0-8])\b/
```

[Use this utility](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range)

Comment: sorry. testing this regex on regex101 didn't match any number from 0-128

Comment: cool..had an extra line break in my regex on regex101. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: 09 is not acceptable.. but this regex seems to allow it. Is there a version to strip leading zeros?

Comment: @Jake: yes: use `\b(\d|1[0-9]|1([0-1]\d|2[0-8]))\b`. Although it is better to learn why it (doesn't) work...

Comment: @Jake: there was a small error in the previous answer: try `\b(\d|[1-9]\d|1([0-1]\d|2[0-8]))\b`.

Comment: That utility is flawed, why do you post a link to it ?

Answer (score 2):

## Excluding 128

You can do this using the following regex:

```
^0?\d{1,2}|1([0-1]\d|2[0-7])$
```

You more or less break it down hierarchically.

The first:

```
0?\d{1,2}
```

captures all values up to (and including) `99`, optionally with a leading zero (so `064`) is accepted.

Next you capture `1[0-1]\d`. These are the values `100` to `119`. This is because there is no constraint on the last digit.

And finally you have `12[0-7]`, the two first digits are fixed, and you can use `120` up to `127`.

## Including 128

In case `128`, is allowed as well, use:

```
^0?\d{1,2}|1([0-1]\d|2[0-8])$
```

## Leading zeros not allowed

The you can use:

```
^\d|[1-9]\d|1([0-1]\d|2[0-8])$
```

## Word boundaries

Here I've added the `^` and `$` so that the string begins and ends with the number. Otherwise, you can use - as @anubhava suggests - word boundaries `\b`. Although one probably better uses:

```
\b(0?\d{1,2}|1([0-1]\d|2[0-7]))\b
\b(0?\d{1,2}|1([0-1]\d|2[0-8]))\b
\b(\d|[1-9]\d|1([0-1]\d|2[0-8]))\b
```

Comment: @vks: no it doesn't. The `|` is bounded less tight than the concat.

Comment: @vks: I tested it with regex101. Otherwise you would have to use `grep` that works on a *line-by-line* setting. It is because it can't handle new lines if it is the beginning and end of the string. As a resolution, I proposed to use word boundaries...

Comment: @vks: that's because you didn't put them within parenthesis and the or binds with the separate `\b`'s.

Comment: @vks: your query is interpreted as `(\b0?\d{1,2})` OR `1([0-1]\d|2[0-7])\b`... If you use brackets it is interpreted as: `\b` concat `0?\d{1,2}|1([0-1]\d|2[0-8])` concat `\b`...

Comment: @vks: and anubhava's answer for instance would accept `09` as well. Don't see problems with that...

Comment: hehehehe good job !!!!!!!!! +1..........was just being pricky!!! good night!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is the wrong tool for the job.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="128" />
```

Done.

Comment: This will probably enable leading zero's which seem - for some reason - not to be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

*0 - 128*  would be: `^(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1[0-1]\d|12[0-8])$`

```
^
(?:
     \d
  |  [1-9] \d
  |  1 [0-1] \d
  |  12 [0-8]
)
$
```